# How to keep slf4j-log4j12 from putting default log4j.properties into JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, logging, jar, log4j

When I build a JAR package including all dependencies with Maven I have the problem that my `log4j.properties` file will be put into the `META-INF` folder but also a default `log4j.properties` goes to the root folder of my JAR. When I run the application with `java -Dlog4j.debug=true -jar application.jar` I can see that log4j is using the one in the root folder:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader 
  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/path/to/application.jar!/log4j.properties] for 
  automatic log4j configuration.
```

When I run the application from IntelliJ everything works as expected.

The relevant part of my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>${project.mainClass}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I remove the properties file from the root folder inside the jar manually log4j can't find my own properties file inside `META-INF`.

So my questions are:

1. How can I avoid the default `log4j.properties` file to be put into the JAR?
2. How can I make log4j find my own `log4j.properties` file inside the JAR?

Comment: Do you have a `log4j.properties` in your project?  If yes, where and why?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I guess I skipped that information.

My `log4j.properties` is in `src/main/resources`.
I have it so I can set the log level to INFO instead of WARN. And yes, I want to distribute that with the JAR.